# How to use a previously built array to build a new object

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

Currently I have an array of objects with properties such as

```
{
id: 1,
rollName: Tuna,
price: 6,
category: sushi,
quantity: 1 // whatever the quantity is that the person selects
}
```

each object is dynamically made through user choice and immediately pushed into the array of which these objects are nested.
What I'm having an issue with, is I now want to make a new array of objects that basically uses the above array goes through it, and makes new objects with properties such as

```
{
rollName: Tuna,
quantity: 1, //whatever the quantity is that the person selects
tableNumber: 1 // preset by page
}
```

Currently I have a function that is

```
function buildOrder(){
        let chefObject = {};
        for (let i = 0; i < tableOneOrder.length; i++) {
        chefObject[i] = {
            rollName : tableOneOrder[i].rollName,
            quantity : tableOneOrder[i].quantity,
            tableNum : tableNum
        };
        }   
    }
```

Id like my final array to be something like

```
[{
rollName: Tuna,
quantity: 3,
tableNumber:1
},{
rollName: Freshwater Eel,
quantity: 2,
tableNumber: 1
},{
rollName: Rainbow Roll,
quantity: 1,
tableNumber: 1
}]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) to iterate over the array and build a new array from its elements. You can also use object destructuring to pull out the fields you want which makes the code a little easier to read:

```js
let arr = [
  {
    id: 1,
    rollName: 'Tuna',
    price: 6,
    category: 'sushi',
    quantity: 1 // whatever the quantity is that the person selects
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    rollName: 'Hamachi',
    price: 7,
    category: 'sushi',
    quantity: 2 // whatever the quantity is that the person selects
  }
]
    
let tableName = 1
let newObj = arr.map(({rollName, quantity}) => ({tableName, quantity, rollName}))

console.log(newObj)
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, it worked.  One thing though, since i'm building the first array with a dropdown using an on("change") function, am i able to access that information outside the function?

Comment: @StephenRice, I'm not quite sure what you're asking. If the data (`arr` in the above code) is being passed in an event handler, you will want to put the above `map()` call in the event handler (or a function called by the event handler). Is that what you mean?

Comment: I meant the object that we constructed was constructed inside a function.  Would I be able to access that object outside the function.  I'm worried about scope.  If say i have the empty object at the top of the page via something like var obj = {}; 
then i have my function that populates the object upon a specific interaction.  
if i were to console.log(obj); then wouldn't it just show me the empty object

Comment: Oh, I see that's an issue regardless of you how you make the object — it's a timing issue not scope. You can always just return the object from the function and  set `obj = returnedObj`. BUT, You need to make sure your console.log only happens after the event that creates the object.